# AWS - EC2 snapshot data stored keep rising even i deleted all snapshots

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

When i saw rising of `1 GB of Amazon Elastic Block Storage snapshot storage`  in Free Tier dashboard, i checked bills and found which region has snapshot.
So i deleted all snapshots and AMI 2 days ago.

But `snapshot data stored under monthly free tier` in bills keep rising every day.
(just one day after it rise 0.1 GB)

I know snapshot cost is really low in my condition, but i'm still wonder even though i deleted all snapshots but keep rising cost.

Actually at first day i changed EC2's region `Virginia -> Seoul` using copied AMI.
Is this the cause? (I deleted it too after that day.)

Comment: RDS also has snapshots. Did you check that?

Comment: I didn't created RDS. And i checked RDS snapshot just now, there is nothing.